# Serverless yaml to whitelist list of ips from Parameter store instead of giving actual values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-api-gateway, serverless

Serverless file :

```
apiGateway:
    metrics: true
    resourcePolicy:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          - execute-api:/${opt:stage}/POST/order*
        Condition:
          IpAddress:
            aws:SourceIp:
              - 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
              - 'xx.xx.x.x/32'
```

I want to update the ips runtime which are available in  ${ssm:/${opt:stage}/natips

How to do that?